# Cabin crew (Air Hostess) job is Good for Muslims

Tags: halal-haram, work, profession

The reason is I like to go that field which Air Hostess.
But there some passenger ask us to give wine or something  which prohibited in Islam while flight travelling. So if a Muslim can I give that to them. If not what is other way

Comment: Don't you mean an Air Steward since you are a male? Also please note that today the term ‘Flight Attendant’ is internationally accepted and most commonly used owing to being gender neutral and more appropriate and more in accordance with their duties as cabin crew.

Answer (score 2):

As salamu alaikum warahmatullah wabarakah.
If you are female, there are a lot more bariers for you, in short the job is not for a muslim girl/women.
But if you are male, then you can't just do the job if you have to serve wine or anything haram. So, before applying to any airline company, you must make that clear, anything haram, you're not going to do. So, you should carefully read terms and conditions. However, if you can't find a job in the airline companies then it's fine, if you sacrifice what you love for Allah, you will get love and satisfaction of Allah, and that's what matters to a muslim.